# AcceptText() not working PowerBuilder

Tags: powerbuilder, datawindow

I have a datawindow with 5 columns: No., Registration date, Name1, Name2, Status. No., Registration date and Status columns are protected after inserting and saving value. After pressing edit i can, or when i open the window, i can only modify Name1 and Name2 values. But every time i open my window (just open it, without even pressing edit), somehow, i can modify the No. column, even i have dw_table.accepttext(). I can't modify Registration date and Status columns (because they are set as protected but so as No. column), but No. column i can. Why?

Comment: Same comment as to your "New Row" question: What you've described isn't native behaviour of the DataWindow, so it must have something to do with your implementation. To give us a chance to answer your question, I'd expect that you need to give us a) the value or expression for Protect (or whatever attribute you're using to "protect" the columns) at design time, and b) any script against that attribute.

Answer (score 0):

AcceptText has nothing to do with whether a field is protected or not. The AcceptText function makes sure the data typed into a field makes it to the internal buffer.